# How to match the list item to content in the file

Tags: python, regex, file

I have a `list1 =  ['hi','world','of']`

I have a .txt file

```
Hellohihowareyou
worldisfullofwonder
```

How to check whether `hi` ,`'of'`, and `world` exists in the  file

pseudo code

```
import re
pattern = r''
for i in list1:
   #print (i)
   with open('file.txt','r'):
       content = f.read()
   test= re.search(pattern,content)
   print (test)
```

My Expected out
`['hi','of']`, since there is no world in the file

Comment: Why regex? You do not seem to need a whole word or case insensitive matching here. Just check `for i in list1: if i in content: results.append(i)`

Comment: The good ol' adage of *"You've got a problem, but thinks you can solve it with regex.  Now you have two problems"* applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
import re
file = 'file.txt'
content = ''
lst =  ['hi','world','of']

with open(file, 'r') as file_handler:
    content = file_handler.read()

result = re.findall('|'.join(lst), content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with `in` keywords, use regex if your pattern start to be more advanced.

### Normal

```py
list1 =  ['hi','world','of']
text = """ Hellohihowareyou
worldisfullofwonder"""
results = []
for element in list1:
    if element in text:
        results.append(element)
print(results)
```

### List comprehension

```py
results = [element for element in list1 if element in text]

print(results)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
file = r'C:\Users\wind\Desktop\file.txt'
list1 = ['hi','of','wonderw']
pattern = r''
for i in list1:
    pattern = re.compile(i, re.IGNORECASE)
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        test= re.search(pattern,content)
        print (test)
```